# Is it possible to send a suggestion that doesn't reply when clicked?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an intent that works with some arbitrary text, like 'do intent blah blah'

I'd like in some cases to send a suggestion for 'do intent' but have it just populate the input with 'do intent ' and not send.

Is this possible?

Specifically I'm focusing on the google assistant at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to configure the behavior of suggestions in this manner. They'll always be sent as the next reply in the conversation when clicked.

Comment: Thanks.  I figure it will require a custom client to do this, but it would have been nice if there was a way.